# Removing a line where the first column is not numeric

Tags: unix, csv, awk

I have a large dataset that is a CSV file and I've already cleaned it up quite a bit. However there are instances where I have a column which is not numeric and I want to remove those rows.

So far I thought something like this would work. I am thinking the solution is probably simple. I am not sure whether I can even do something like this. It is a CSV file so I tried to tell awk that its delimited by commas. Also an example of a good value in column one is this: 323870133825187840

```
awk '/,/$1 != numeric'
```

Are there any suggestions on this one. I initially thought about doing some kind of a one liner such as, [0-9], etc. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me out with this. For someone out there this is probably like child's play :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you're only dealing with unsigned integer values, you can use either:

```
awk -F, '$1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/'
```

or

```
awk -F, '$1 !~ /[^[:digit:]]/'
```

Both use the 'implicit print' action.  The first checks that `$1` only contains digits; the second checks that `$1` does not contain a non-digit.

If your numbers are more general (signed, possibly with decimal point, possibly with exponential notation — 6.0221413e+23 (Avogadro's number), for example), then you need a more complex regular expression and will use positive matching, only selecting rows where field 1 matches your regex for a valid number.

Comment: The first option worked like a charm. Thank you very much. Now all the data in my CSV file is in perfect order and the java code I wrote works great! THANK YOU, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Also is there any good tutorials or webpages that you or someone else could recommend how to learn awk or sed? I would like not to have to come to the boards every time I want to do something using the unix commands.

Comment: There used to be an O'Reilly book on Awk and Sed; a quick search shows you could still buy them (http://search.oreilly.com/?q=sed+awk).  I learned from the [7th Edition UNIX™ Programmer's Manuals (Vols 1 & 2)](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan), but modern versions of the commands are more powerful than the 1978 versions were. The GNU manuals ([gawk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/) and [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/)) are not too bad, either.

Comment: Thank you very much. I may just look into that.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply grep it:

```
grep -P '^[+-]?\d*(\.\d+)?(?<=.),' file
```

This will return lines if it finds decimal/integer number in first column with optional `=/-` sign.

For ex following numbers will be matched in column 1:

```
6.72
1235.3
72
.66
2.8
+3.5
-5.9
```

PS: Empty column value in 1st column will not be matched.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk -F, '$1+0 != $1{next}1' csvFile
```

Comment: Please add a short write-up to explain your code. Just pasting code is not acceptable.

Comment: There is not much to explain. The code just does what the OP asked for: "I have a column which is not numeric and I want to remove those rows."